# segmentation fault result

Tags: c, linux

I was trying to execute the following code on the Linux installed on the desktop as well as the same linux installed in virtual machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int *ptr;
  printf("%d\n",*ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

I was surprised to see the results
on linux installed directly on desktop it gives "segmentation fault" 
whereas on linux installed on virtual machine it prints some junk value.
Can anyone please help me out to understand why is it so?

Comment: Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. Buggy code is much harder to understand than correct code.

Comment: This is called "undefined behavior". You can't tell what it might do.

Comment: Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. "Undefined" means that anything can happen. You can receive a segmentation fault. Or the value can be garbage. Or your computer can explode. Anything goes.

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer is not initialized. Initialize it like below:

```
int a = 42;
int *ptr = &a;
```

Dereferencing a non initialized pointer invokes undefined behavior,  your `printf`  call can print some garbage or just crash.

May I suggest you to read a book on C programming?

Comment: I know that we should initialize the pointer, as it's memory in not withing the program's control. It might or might not point to the memory map of the program, so it's behavior will be undefined. My concern is that why it does not give a segmentation fault on virtual machine. I tried to compile and run it 100 times but it always gave junk value. I it would have given segmentation fault at least once I might have not posted this question. Can you please tell that has it some relation with virtual machine. Could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are dealing with "UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR". Exactly what happens isn't defined. It may crash, it may burn, or it may do something else expected or unexpected.

In this particular case, it's probably to with the value that `ptr` gets from being on the stack - it will have a valid memory address on the virtual machine, so you get some random bits of memory that you don't know what it is. On the non-virtual machine, the value is different [or memory is located differently] and you get a seg-fault for accessing an invalid memory location.

There is NOTHING useful to be gained from accessing a pointer that hasn't been set to anything, but it's far from guaranteed to crash. It may just as well print whatever is at that memory address.

Comment: ya but it always give some value which will be constant but the address pointed to gets changed for each run. Is there any possibility that any uninitialized memory in virtual machine contains some specific value. I know it might not be true but just asked as a matter of curiosity

Comment: The virtual machine should behave just like the same system on bare-metal. But there may be differences in where things end up in memory for a huge number of reasons. And no, it's not necessarily the same every time either - modern OS's have "address space randomisation", which moves things around in memory from one run to another.

Answer (score 1):

You have uninitialised pointer. Pointer is just like integer with the address to which points. Since its uninitialised, it may contain *any* value. So on your VPS it may point to some valid address that your process can access and on your computer it points to something unknown that the process cant access.